# Need help with returning a 2D array C++, please

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an array and pass it to functions, which then return it, but I don't know the correct way of returning.
I've been looking around tutorials and trying stuff out, but haven't managed to solve this.
I'm new to C++ and thought it would be similar to Java, but apparently it isn't.

This is where I've gotten:

```
class MainClass {

public:
    static int countLetterCombinations(string array[], int numberOfWords) {
        // Code
        return totalCombos;
    }


    // This is the function I'm having trouble with.
    static string** sortCombos(string combinations[][3]) {
            // Do something
        return combinations; // This gives converting error.
    }

};


int main() {

// Code

int numberOfCombinations = MainClass::countLetterCombinations(words, numberOfWords);

string combinations[numberOfCombinations][3];

combinations = MainClass::sortCombos(combinations);

// Further code

}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm new to C++ and don't have experience with vectors. But I'm trying the solution by DeadMG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a `vector`. C++ stack-based arrays cannot be dynamically sized- oh, and you can't convert `[][]` to `**`, the conversion only works for the first dimension. Oh, and you can't assign to arrays, either.

The simple rule is, in C++, never use primitive arrays- they're just a headache. They're inherited from C, which actually defined a lot of it's array behaviour for source compatibility with B, which is insanely old. Use classes that manage dynamic memory for you, like `std::vector`, for dynamically sizable arrays.

`std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>> combinations(numberOfCombinations);`

```
static void sortCombos(std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>>& combinations) {
        // Do something
} // This function modifies combinations in-place and doesn't require a return.
```

Oh, and you really don't have to make functions static class members- they can just go in the global namespace.

Comment: And take care to put a space between the closing brackets of nested templates, unless you are using a C++0x-compiler ;)

Comment: What does the "& combinations" do?

Comment: @Kristjan: It takes by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I got it working. But I had to remove the "3" from function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your sortCombos method can modify the array parameter in-place, and the caller will see those changes directly.  Because you doesn't need to return anything, you should change the return type to void.

Even if you could return input array, you can't assign to combinations.